# Copy conditional formatting with custom format

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to copy conditional formatting that compares this cell with the cell adjacent to it. In a nutshell it's supposed to look like this:

```
If A1<B1, make it green, if A1>B1, make it red
If A2<B2, make it green, if A2>B2, make it red
If A3<B3, make it green, if A3>B3, make it red
...
```

Right now if I copy the cell or select + drag, it will turn into this:

```
If A1<B1, make it green, if A1>B1, make it red
If A2<B1, make it green, if A2>B1, make it red
If A3<B1, make it green, if A3>B1, make it red
...
```

I.e. the comparison target remains fixed.
How do I copy conditional formatting that has dynamic comparison cell?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Custom formula rule you apply for Row 1 has an Apply to range that includes all the required rows.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting formulas should not be *copied*, they should be *applied to a range*. State the formula as it works for the cell A1 (or whatever the upper left corner of the range is), and it will work correctly for the entire range, using relative references — even if there is no explicit indication that it does so.